# Connected to wifi, no internet

Tags: wireless, broadcom, macbook-pro

I have a macbook late 2007 with Broadcom Limited BCM4321 running Ubuntu 17.10.
I can connect to wifi, but it shows a question mark and there is no internet.
help?

`sudo dmesg | tail -f` :

```
[  127.813093] RDX: 00007ffed9b95810 RSI: 00000000c05064a7 RDI: 0000000000000008
[  127.813096] RBP: 0000000000000020 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 00007f5ef87edc00
[  127.813100] R10: ffffffffffffffb0 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007f5ef8a69c20
[  127.813103] R13: 0000000000000008 R14: 00007f5ef8a69c78 R15: 0000000000000000
[  127.813107] Code: ff e8 1a cf 77 e4 48 8b 7d a0 48 8d 75 a8 e8 ad 21 7c e4 45 85 ff 0f 85 0c ff ff ff 44 89 e6 48 c7 c7 d8 3b 12 c0 e8 46 d4 7d e4 <0f> ff e9 f6 fe ff ff 0f 1f 40 00 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 
[  127.813198] ---[ end trace 31f49c28f11a204a ]---
[  128.657356] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  128.657363] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  128.657370] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  132.054657] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

wireless info script result:

https://pastebin.com/XFYkuRfM

Comment: which wifi card are you using?

Comment: The one that's inside, no external wifi cards.

Comment: and what card is it? brand and model

Comment: I belive it is Broadcom Limited BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 03)

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo dmesg | tail -f` to the question.

Comment: added the output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you still have issues after following the relevant answer to the linked question, could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: tried to install Broadcom Wireless Drivers, it didn't work. added the link of my  network diagnostics to the question.

Comment: I fixed it, I had to remove the proprietary Broadcam driver and it fixed the problem!